# What should the column and length be for a column of this decimal

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, decimal

I have the following decimal:

`132.24590781249998`

It can also be as short as:

`132.2`

what should my `mysql` column be and the `length` of this column so it stores the value from as short to as long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it

```
decimal(20,14)
```

where 20 is the maximum number of digits and 14 is the number of digits to the right of decimal point. You can refer [decimal datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html). Also note that in case of values which are having less number of digits to the right of decimal will have 0 added, so for that you need to format it while selecting or retrieving the data.

Comment: Also consider plain `DOUBLE`.